# networking applets not working in chrome

Tags: java, sockets, google-chrome, applet, socket.io

I have recently created a Java applet which creates a socket and performs some networking functions. The applet works fine when run in an **applet viewer**. But when i try to run it in a 
**google chrome**, it is launched but its not performing the desired function.

I used (ofcourse) `java.net` library and my applet runs without a main method.(Old applets unlike *swing components*).

Is not having a main method a problem ??? Please help :) thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after a bit of research i came to know that Java applets have many restrictions due to security reasons... which include specially  on creating the **SOCKETS!!**. 
If you really wanted to communicate using Applet then you have to run it independently, to accomplish this you should have the applet **digitally signed** which is too tough to obtain.

Instead you can create the JAR version of the applet and then convert into exe application using **jar2exe** converter and use it.